# Partition/boot issues - is there boot tool who can re-set partitions or format laptop hard drive clean?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, format

I had Ubuntu 17.10 installed on laptop but it was getting heavy on my old machine- so I backed everything up on an external hard drive and tried to boot Lubuntu from flash drive stick and install along side as dual boot.
The first time I got an error, so I tried again- only this time when it asked me I choose to install Lubuntu OVER Ubuntu- a partition managing slider appeared again- but this time displayed 3 possible OS Ubuntu, Lubuntu, and another Lubuntu...This proceess also failed and OS was not installed.

Now my laptop doesn't boot to any of the OS...It doesn't give the option to type any DOS commend either (shows an unblinking _).
 My question is: is there a specific tool I can use running from a bootable flash drive to wipe clean the hard drive (reset any existing partitions)? I have 2 more computers that run on Xubuntu to make the bootable flash drive (UNetbootin is the easiest for me to use).

Comment: I'd boot your install media; use 'try ubuntu' and then load `gparted` to do what you need/want to do with your partitions.  I usually setup my partitions manually prior to install, writing them down on scrap paper then start install, select 'something else' & use the partitions I'd written down.  I also usually have different size partitions to reduce errors in case UUID/names aren't confusing

Comment: "first time I got an error" seems important. Exactly what error? Is your question about the error?  If so, please provide more information (we are not psychic.) If not, why did you bring it up?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu installer normaly gives you the option to "Use whole disk" or something similar. Also "Something else" which will let you do the partitioning manually.

Comment: I was counting on that - but it shows me error during the attempts to install. With every attempt showing an additional partition (for example, after 5 tries it would have shown 6 partitions- limiting the "new" attempt to one of those).